# Angular 4 : click on one specific item

Tags: angular, for-loop, click

I am working on a table that looks like this : 
[image]

I try to print details on a specific item when the button is clicked. But for the moment when I clicked one on the buttons, I display the details of all items.

I'm using a for loop and this is why I have this problem, a part of my code is below :

```
<div *ngFor="let incident of incidentsHist"> 
   <div class="wrap-table70" *ngIf="this.incident['tableData'][0]['tableDataList'][0]">
    <div class="table-alert">

      <div class="row">

        <div class="cell" data-title="Babylon Ref">  {{this.incident['tableData'][0]['tableDataList'][0]['babylon_ref']}} </div>
        <div class="cell" data-title="Incident Name" > </div>
        <div class="cell" data-title="Alarm Name" > </div> 
        ...
        <div class="cell" data-title="Details" > 
          <button  type="button" class="btn-xs btn-primary active" (click)="details=!details " autofocus ng-model="details" >

                <div *ngIf="!details"> Details </div> 
                <div *ngIf="details"> Close </div>

          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to get a click action on only one clicked item and not the others ? 
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `incident.details` for hide show details

```
  <div class="row">

    <div class="cell" data-title="Babylon Ref">  {{this.incident['tableData'][0]['tableDataList'][0]['babylon_ref']}} </div>
    <div class="cell" data-title="Incident Name" > </div>
    <div class="cell" data-title="Alarm Name" > </div> 
    ...
    <div class="cell" data-title="Details" > 
      <button  type="button" class="btn-xs btn-primary active" (click)="incident.details=!incident.details " autofocus>

            <div *ngIf="!incident.details"> Details </div> 
            <div *ngIf="incident.details"> Close </div>

      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use `index` value to do so inside `*ngFor`.**

**Change:** `*ngFor="let incident of incidentsHist; let i = index"`

Here is updated code:

```
<div *ngFor="let incident of incidentsHist; let i = index"> 
   <div class="wrap-table70" *ngIf="this.incident['tableData'][0]['tableDataList'][0]">
    <div class="table-alert">

      <div class="row">

        <div class="cell" data-title="Babylon Ref">  {{this.incident['tableData'][0]['tableDataList'][0]['babylon_ref']}} </div>
        <div class="cell" data-title="Incident Name" > </div>
        <div class="cell" data-title="Alarm Name" > </div> 
        ...
        <div class="cell" data-title="Details" > 
          <button  type="button" class="btn-xs btn-primary active" (click)="details[i]=!details[i]" autofocus>

                <div *ngIf="!details[i]"> Details </div> 
                <div *ngIf="details[i]"> Close </div>

          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```